# LinkedHashSet on objects without overridden hashCode() and equals()

Tags: java, generics, equals, hashcode, linkedhashset

I have the following collection of objects:

```
Set<MyClass> test = new LinkedHashSet<MyClass>();
```

but `MyClass` does not override the `hashcode` and `equals` methods.

Can have the above collection only unique objects even the MyClass does not override the `hashCode` and `equals` methods?

Comment: It will contain unique objects according to identity, but not according to whatever other definition of equality you have. If you want the collection to contain unique objects according to some non-identity definition of equality, override those methods.

Comment: [You could resort to commons collections and implement an external hash and equality provider](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20030782/521799)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default implementation of `equals` is to check identity (i.e., use the `==` operator). Your `LinkedHashSet` (or any other `HashSet`, for that case) will contain unique objects in the sense you won't be able to add the same object twice. However, if you create two instance exactly the same way (e.g., pass the same arguments to the constructor), your set will still contain both of them, as they are not `equals`.

Comment: what is the solution to this ? 2 same instances are getting added to my linkedHashSet