# HashMap implementation that allows to override hash and equals method

Tags: java, hashmap

In Java you can override the equals and hash method of the HashMap's key object to determine how the hash code is generated and when two key objects should be considered equal.

Is there any Map implementation that allows to define the hash and equals on in the Map class by overriding its hash method (and determining key equality by an equals(key1,key2) method that can be overridden)?

**Use case:**

Ĺets assume we have a Objects of class GeoData, containing the fields:  country, region, city. We want access two Maps: map ***x*** stores the number of inhabitants of each region and map ***y*** the number of inhabitants of each city.

To get both informations for a GeoData object we first need to extract country and region from that object, then create a new Object of class X that defines hash and equals considering country and region and use it as key for map ***x***. Additionally we need to do the same with country, region and city. Create a new Object of class Y and use that get the value from map ***y***.

Wouldn't it be easier if we extend a Map implementation for each of these maps ***x*** and ***y*** and override a hash(GeoData key) and equals(GeoData key1,GeoData key2) method, which would also avoid to create new key objects for every access?

hash(GeoData key) could then either use country and region in map ***x***, or country,region and city in map ***y*** for hash code calculation.

**UPDATE:**

Correctly marked as duplicate. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20030782/2148569) answer suggesting apache commons-collections AbstractHashMap is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use the same key type (`GeoData`) with different equality criteria in different `Map`s.

You can do that if instead of `HashMap` you use a `TreeMap` and pass a different `Comparator<GeoData>` to each `TreeMap` constructor (one will compare two `GeoData` instances by comparing country,region and city and the other will only compare the country and region).

Answer (score 2):

You could also create a decorator for a map. It doesn't avoid creating a new class for a key, but it hides it so the map is of type `Map<GeoData, Integer>`. Of course if you do things like `keySet()`, city will have to be always null since this information is lost (it is not part of the key).

```
public class Country {}
public class Region {}
public class City {}

public class GeoData {

    public final Country country;
    public final Region region;
    public final City city;

    public GeoData(Country country, Region region, City city) {
        this.country = country;
        this.region = region;
        this.city = city;
    }
}

public class InhabitantsInRegion  implements Map<GeoData, Integer> {

    private static class InnerKey {

        private final Country country;
        private final Region region;

        private InnerKey(Country country, Region region) {
            this.country = country;
            this.region = region;
        }

        // hashcode & equals
    }

    private final Map<InnerKey, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return map.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return map.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return key instanceof GeoData && map.containsKey(newInnerKey((GeoData) key));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return map.containsValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(Object key) {
        if (key instanceof GeoData) {
            return map.get(newInnerKey((GeoData) key));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer put(GeoData key, Integer value) {
        return map.put(new InnerKey(key.country, key.region), value);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends GeoData, ? extends Integer> m) {
        m.entrySet().forEach(entry -> put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }

    @Override
    public Integer remove(Object key) {
        if (key instanceof GeoData) {
            return map.remove(newInnerKey((GeoData) key));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        map.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<GeoData> keySet() {
        return map.keySet().stream()
                .map(InhabitantsInRegion::newGeoDataKey)
                .collect(toSet());
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Integer> values() {
        return map.values();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<GeoData, Integer>> entrySet() {
        return map.entrySet().stream()
                .map(this::newEntry)
                .collect(toSet());
    }



    private Entry<GeoData, Integer> newEntry(Entry<InnerKey, Integer> entry) {
        return new Entry<GeoData, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public GeoData getKey() {
                return newGeoDataKey(entry.getKey());
            }

            @Override
            public Integer getValue() {
                return entry.getValue();
            }

            @Override
            public Integer setValue(Integer value) {
                return map.put(entry.getKey(), value);
            }
        };
    }

    private static InnerKey newInnerKey(GeoData geoDataKey) {
        return new InnerKey(geoDataKey.country, geoDataKey.region);
    }

    private static GeoData newGeoDataKey(InnerKey innerKey) {
        return new GeoData(innerKey.country, innerKey.region, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper / decorator class that takes the key object in constructor argument and computes its `hashCode` and `equals` the way you need. Then use this wrapper class as the key instead of the original key.