# Bundle - is key case sensitive?

Tags: android, bundle

I'm using Bundle to send data.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putDouble("x", this.Location.X);
b.putDouble("y", this.Location.Y);
```

Is key case sensitive?

Comment: Have you tested it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bundle and other Key Mapping mechanism are case sensitive.

For more discussion [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8236945/593709)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a simple Map, so probably. Why don't you test it?

EDIT:
The key is a String. `"x".equals("X") == false`