# Bundle losing values

Tags: java, android

I'm new to java.
I'm trying to save variables from `OnSaveInstanceState`, to `OnCreate` when the screen rotates.
I've logged the values saved into the `savedInstanceState` Bundle. 
When the screen rotates the Bundle values in `OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` show on the log as 0's, but show as the correct values in the log for `OnSaveInstanceState`.

My Activity Java is

```
package com.hfad.stopwatch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StopwatchActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = StopwatchActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private int seconds;
    private boolean running;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stopwatch);
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() Restoring previous state");
            /* restore state */
            seconds = savedInstanceState.getInt("seconds");
            running = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("running");
            String tmpStr = String.valueOf(seconds);
            Log.d(TAG,tmpStr);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() ending");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() No saved state available");
            /* initialize app */
        }
        runTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG,"onSaveInstanceState() saving state");
        savedInstanceState.putInt("Seconds", seconds);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("running", running);
        String tmpStr = String.valueOf(savedInstanceState.getInt("Seconds"));
        Log.d(TAG,tmpStr);
        Log.d(TAG,"onSaveInstanceState() ending");
    }

    //Start the stopwatch running when the start button is clicked
    public void onClickStart(View view){
        running = true;
    }

    //Stop the stopwatch running when the stop button is clicked
    public void onClickStop(View view){
        running = false;
    }

    //Start the stopwatch running when the start button is clicked
    public void onClickReset(View view){
        running = false;
        seconds = 0;
    }

    private void runTimer(){
        final TextView timeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_view);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                int hours = seconds/3600;
                int minutes = (seconds%3600)/60;
                int secs = seconds%60;
                String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d",hours,minutes,secs);
                timeView.setText(time);
                if(running){
                    seconds++;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is the Log.

```
07-26 21:02:19.880 6124-6124/com.hfad.stopwatch D/StopwatchActivity: onSaveInstanceState() saving state

07-26 21:02:19.880 6124-6124/com.hfad.stopwatch D/StopwatchActivity: 11

07-26 21:02:19.880 6124-6124/com.hfad.stopwatch D/StopwatchActivity: onSaveInstanceState() ending

07-26 21:02:19.940 6124-6124/com.hfad.stopwatch D/StopwatchActivity: onCreate() Restoring previous state

07-26 21:02:19.940 6124-6124/com.hfad.stopwatch D/StopwatchActivity: 0

07-26 21:02:19.940 6124-6124/com.hfad.stopwatch D/StopwatchActivity: onCreate() ending
```

I'm following lessons in a book, but this does not work as explained, and I can't find a solution online.

Comment: you should mark one of the answers as accepted if it helped you. Please follow the rules of SO.

Answer (score 3):

You're using a wrong key to find the value. There is a capital `S` in your key. Keys in a `Bundle` are case sensitive.

A good practice here would be to declare the key string as a final static and use them to store and retrieve. E.g.

```
public static final String SECONDS_KEY = "seconds";
public static final String RUNNING_KEY = "running"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)` after set the values you want to save.

You can see more [in the documentations](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Answer (score 1):

Bundle is case-sensitive. You are putting in "Seconds" and retrieving "seconds". Good practice is to define the keys as constants so you don't experience such a mistake.

[Bundle - is key case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210548/bundle-is-key-case-sensitive)

Comment: Thank you, Following the examples makes me blind to typo's.