# How can I make a case insensitive keyset ConcurrentHashMap in java?

Tags: java, generics, extends, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to replace my use of `ConcurrentHashMap` with mine `CaseInsensitiveConcurrentHashMap`.  However, I cannot instantiate my hashmap.  I will provide my implementations.

The hash map class - based from SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8237007/850475

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class CaseInsensitiveConcurrentHashMap <T> extends ConcurrentHashMap<String, T>{

    @Override
    public T put(String key, T value) {
        return super.put(key.toLowerCase(), value);
    }

    public T get(String key) {
        return super.get(key.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

And my code below that does not work with the new hash map:

```
public class tester {
    private static ConcurrentMap<String, SomeClass> items = new CaseInsensitiveConcurrentHashMap<String, SomeClass>();  
    private static ConcurrentMap<String, CaseInsensitiveConcurrentHashMap<String, Collection<SomeClass2>>> tagMap = new CaseInsensitiveConcurrentHashMap<String, CaseInsensitiveConcurrentHashMap<String, Collection<SomeClass2>>>();
}
```

Both lines in `tester` fail. This is my error message:

`Incorrect number of arguments for type CaseInsensitiveConcurrentHashMap<T>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, Collection<SomeClass>>`

Any idea as of what I can try?

Comment: Your map has only one type parameter, so you should pass it only one (remove the `String`s)

Comment: Be aware, that your get method is not going to get called since it is not overriding Map.get().  You should also override the other put methods in ConcurrentHashMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CaseInsensitiveConcurrentHashMap has only one generalized parameter for the values, so it should be instanced using `new CaseInsensitiveConcurrentHashMap<SomeClass>()`

Comment: Will this index the generic class by `String`?

Comment: @StephenD By extending `ConcurrentHashMap<String, T>`, `CaseInsensitiveConcurrentHashMap` has already provided `String` as the type argument for keys.

Comment: Yes it should using case insensitive keys. Also note that a much better approach would be using composition over inheritance since you can't be sure that all methods will self-use the overridden put() (eg. putAll).

Comment: Is there a way to allow initializing a new instance like `ConcurrentMap
<String, Collection<SomeClass>> cichm = new CaseInsensitiveConcurrentHashMap<String, Collection<SomeClass>>();` ?

Comment: Your solution works for me.  +1 if I can find a way to use it the way in my last comment question

Comment: It would be enough to parametrize the generic class with 2 parameters, anyway since the implementation relies on the fact that the keys are strings there's no point in doing that.

Answer (score 3):

```
class CaseInsensitiveConcurrentHashMap <T>
```

Your hashmap takes a single generic parameter.

Therefore, when you use it, you must pass only one generic parameter.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I can initialize this new map with key value pair of `String` to `T`?

Comment: @StephenD: What don't you understand?

Comment: Well, initializing a regular `ConcurrentMap`, you can initialize with `<String, SomeClass>` rather than only `<SomeClass>`