# How can i put data in a HashMap<String, Integer> where I don't want duplicate key like string=a and string=A should be same

Tags: java, hashmap

How can i put data in a HashMap where I don't want duplicate keys like string=a and string=A should be same.

eg:`HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("A", 37);
map.put("a", 37);`

I want both A and a should be considered same.

Comment: Update first parameter to all capital or all letter cases

Comment: @dotnetom thanks, I already got out from this problem by taking first parameter in lower cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is Java

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CaseInsensitiveMap extends HashMap<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String put(String key, String value) {
       return super.put(key.toLowerCase(), value);
    }

    // not @Override because that would require the key parameter to be of type Object
    public String get(String key) {
       return super.get(key.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Soluce by @Vishal [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236945/case-insensitive-string-as-hashmap-key)