# Ignore case while comparing string with keyvalue in the hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, ignore-case

I am trying to check if my hashmap key set contains the string 'buffSB.toString()'. But I wanted to compare ignoring case (upper or lower).

```
static StringBuilder buffSB = new StringBuilder(); 

buffSB.append(alphabet);

Map<String, String> pref =  new Datamatch().main();  // Getting the Hashmap from other class

if(pref.containsKey(buffSB.toString()))             //This is where I need to ignore case while searching string in the map key set 
  { 
      String val = pref.get(buffSB.toString());
  }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the implementation of HashMap getKey method you have to pass the proper key to generate the hash value and get the actual value from that bucket.

```
    if (key == null)
        return getForNullKey();
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
         e != null;
         e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
            return e.value;
    }
    return null;
```

Three solutions

```
    Map<String, String> pref = new TreeMap<String, String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

OR

```
    Map<String, String> map = new CaseInsensitiveMap<String, String>();
```

OR

```
    Looping through map with the ignore case
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to use TreeMap which enable providing a comparator to its constructor:

`Map<String, String> yourMap= 
 new TreeMap<String, String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`

see [Case insensitive string as HashMap key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236945/case-insensitive-string-as-hashmap-key)

Answer (score 2):

Only use lowercase keys:

```
map.put(key.toLowercase(), value);
// later
String val = map.get(someKey.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: And if he absolutely needs the strings to have Uppercases and Lowercases? Like names for example...

Comment: this has the benefit of avoiding duplicate keys that differ only by case.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `CaseInsensitiveMap<K,V>` instead of `Map<K,V>`

It extends `AbstractHashedMap<K,V>` and it ignores case of keys.
You can create a new instance of this map by passing the existing case-sensitive map to the constructor.

Consider this example:

```
Map<String, String> map = new CaseInsensitiveMap<String, String>();
map.put("One", "One");
map.put("Two", "Two");
map.put(null, "Three");
map.put("one", "Four");
```

The map will contains three elements:

```
<one, "Four">
<two, "Two">
<null, "Three">
```

Infact `map.put("one", "Four")` overwrites the value insert with `map.put("One", "One")`.

`map.get(null)` returns "Three".

`map.get("ONE")`, `map.get("one")`, `map.get("One")`, and so on returns "Four".

Keep in mind that the `keySet()` method returns all lowercase keys, or nulls.

`keySet()` equals `{"one", "two", null}`.

[Further documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/CaseInsensitiveMap.html#CaseInsensitiveMap%28java.util.Map%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the `keySet` of the map, for each key, use the string function `equalsIgnoreCase` to compare:

```
    Map<String, String> pref = new Datamatch().main();  // Getting the Hashmap from other class

    String val;
    for (String key : pref.keySet()) {
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(buffSB.toString())) {
            val = pref.get(key);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pref.containsKey(buffSB.toString().toLowerCase())
```

Use string.toUpperCase() or string.toLowerCase() to ignore case.

Comment: if pref contains "Hello". what would be the result for "HELLO" or "hello"?