# ReduceComplexity Or Any Optimized logic to HashMap Values are replaced against keys contains the Paragraph String Array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, optimization, foreach

I have `Object` **Array** named `paragraph` and a `Hashmap` Object named `g_hMapValues`. What I am doing in this code is iterating throughout the array `paragraph` and put it into the Text and Replacing the String (**If it matched with the keys**) corresponding to their hashmap values.

> **Note** :- Please don't take care of class `Text`. it is working fine to me. What i need to do is optimize the logic (**Nested Loop**), because my paragraph may contains hundreds of thousands of records.

```
for(String keys : this.g_hMapValues.keySet()){ //hmapValues have some 20-30 key pair Values

        for (Object text : paragraph) { //paragraph may Contains 100000 of record.
            Text textElement = (Text) text;
            System.out.println(textElement.getValue());
            if (textElement.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(keys)) {
                textElement.setValue(String.valueOf(this.g_hMapValues.get(keys)));
            }
        }
        }
```

I have a limited number of keys but it may exists in multiple `paragraph` and many times too. I didn't find any optimized logic to do that and it consumes so much time to respond to a `REST Service`.

I need to Optimize this iteration because during debugging i found that this iteration takes more time than usual.

Comment: > My paragraph is also updating each time if keys are replaced with those paragraphs. So Please help me out ...

Comment: where you typed "lacs" did you mean "lots"?

Comment: @Rob lac (or lakh) is Indian word meaning 100 000

Comment: well Awesome I learned a new word  :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to iterate through the hashmap's `keySet`. Iterate only through the `paragraph` array and check if the map contains current `textElement`.   Example:

```
for (Object text : paragraph) { //paragraph may Contains 100000 of record.
    Text textElement = (Text) text;
    System.out.println(textElement.getValue());
    if (this.g_hMapValues.contains(textElement.getValue())) {
        textElement.setValue(String.valueOf(this.g_hMapValues.get(keys)));
    }
}
```

If case sensitivity is an issue, you can have a look at question [Case insensitive string as HashMap key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236945/case-insensitive-string-as-hashmap-key).