# How to simplify if statement

Tags: java

I'm using eclipse to code a program. Is there any way to simplify this if statement?

```
 if(departmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("Business Management")){
        departmentName = "SBM";
      }
      if(departmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("Chemical & Life Sciences")){
        departmentName = "SCL";
      }
      if(departmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("Design")){
        departmentName = "SDN";
      }
      if(departmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("Engineering")){
        departmentName = "SEG";
      }
      if(departmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("Oral Health Therapy")){
        departmentName = "SHS(AH)";
      }
      if(departmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("Nursing")){
        departmentName = "SHS(N)";
      }
```

Comment: as a side node. make it more null save: "Chemical & Life Sciences".equalsIgnoreCase(departmentName)

Comment: use switch case

Comment: you can use switch statement for this purpose 
: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JDK 7, you can use `switch` statement on `String` object.
See this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html). or check @Tim Biegeleisen's answer.

Using `switch` would not noticeably improve the performance, although your code will be more compact and readable.

In case you are using an older JDK version, I will suggest you to correct your code, since you are doing possible unnecessary checks:

```
 if(departmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("Business Management")){
     departmentName = "SBM";
 }
 else if(departmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("Chemical & Life Sciences")){
     departmentName = "SCL";
 }
 else if(departmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("Design")){
     departmentName = "SDN";
 }
 else if(departmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("Engineering")){
     departmentName = "SEG";
 }
 else if(departmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("Oral Health Therapy")){
     departmentName = "SHS(AH)";
 }
 else if(departmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("Nursing")){
     departmentName = "SHS(N)";
 }
```

Comment: You will not notice `switch` optimization until you are not comparing hundreds of `string`s

Comment: More likely thousands, or running the `switch` in a tight loop of thousands of iterations. :-) But that's not the same as it not being there. Good edit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `switch` statement, and compare the case insensitive department name against your various expected values.

```
if (departmentName == null) return;
switch(departmentName.toLowerCase()) {
    case "business management":
        departmentName = "SBM";
        break;

    case "chemical & life sciences":
        departmentName = "SCL";
        break;

    // other cases
    default:
        "Not Found";
       break;
}
```

Note that I do a return in case the department name be `null`.  You may handle `null` however you want, so long as you don't let your code try to switch on that null value.

Answer (score 1):

[Tim's `switch` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46361276/157247) is probably the way to go.

But another alternative would be to store those mappings in a `Map<String,String>` and then get them via

```
departmentName = theMap.get(departmentName);
```

To handle the case-insensitive aspect, either store the entries under keys that are all lower case and use

```
departmentName = theMap.get(departmentName.toLowerCase());
```

or look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236945/case-insensitive-string-as-hashmap-key) for other ways to do the case-insensitive part.