# Case insensitive hashmap for strings in java

Tags: java, case, superclass

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236945/case-insensitive-string-as-hashmap-key) for a case insensitive hashmap and tried to implement it but I'm not getting the expected result. For some reason it's not returning the value when I do get with a different casing and is returning null, and I thought that you didn't really need a non-default constructor in this case but I'm not sure.

```
public class CaseInsensitiveMap extends HashMap<String, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer put(String key, Integer value) {
       return super.put(key.toLowerCase(), value);
    }

    // not @Override because that would require the key parameter to be of type Object
    public Integer get(String key) {
       return super.get(key.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

and used like so;

```
HashMap<String, Integer> stuff = new CaseInsensitiveMap();
stuff.put("happy", 11);
System.out.println(stuff);
Integer result = stuff.get("HAPPy");
System.out.println(result);
System.out.println(stuff);
```

but result is;

```
{happy=11}
null
{happy=11}
```

Comment: same link but different answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22336599/2310289 - using case insensitive treemap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple fix;

```
CaseInsensitiveMap stuff = new CaseInsensitiveMap();
```

prints out;

```
{happy=11}
11
{happy=11}
```

`CaseInsensitiveMap` is extending `HashMap<String, Integer>` so it is a subclass of it, the fact that you reference `stuff` as `HashMap` (as the superclass) allows it to use default `get` method. You can even see in an IDE that your custom `get(String)` in `CaseInsensitiveMap` is not even used.

Only overridden methods will be used if you use superclass reference for a subclass, as you've done in your code. That is why only your custom `put(String, Integer)` method works since it is overriding the method in `super`.

[Referencing Subclass objects with Subclass vs Superclass reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/referencing-subclass-objects-subclass-vs-superclass-reference/) for more info on that issue.

Answer (score 1):

As `String` is marked as `final`, may consider extends `CharSequence`

```
public class CaseInsensitiveMap<K extends CharSequence, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    private Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return map.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return map.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return map.containsKey(key.toString().toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return map.containsValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return map.get(key.toString().toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return map.put((K) key.toString().toLowerCase(), value);
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        return map.remove(key.toString().toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        map.putAll(m);      
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        map.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return map.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return map.values();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, V> > entrySet() {
        return map.entrySet();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return map.toString();
    }

}
```

The testing class needed to modified as the following:

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Integer> stuff = new CaseInsensitiveMap<String, Integer>();

        stuff.put("happy", 11);
        System.out.println(stuff);
        Integer result = stuff.get("HAPPy");
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(stuff);

    }
}
```