# How to ignore the case sensitive when we look for a key in the Map?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good way to have a Map<String, ?> get and put ignoring case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212562/is-there-a-good-way-to-have-a-mapstring-get-and-put-ignoring-case)

How to ignore case sensitive when searching a key in the java.util.Map?

I want to know whether we can look up for a key in the map by ignoring the case.

```
Example,
   Map<String, Integer> lookup = new HashMap<String, Integer>();   
   lookup.put("one", 1);   
   lookup.put("two", 2);   
   lookup.put("three", 3);
```

The user input might be "ONE" or "one". in such a case instead of converting the user input to lowercase. is there is any way to ignore the key sensitive via any methods?

Thanks,
Kathir

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Why not use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead of `HashMap`, then you could specify a Comparator with a case insensitive order ([`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Map<String, Integer> lookup = 
        new TreeMap<String, Integer>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    lookup.put("One", 1);
    lookup.put("tWo", 2);
    lookup.put("thrEE", 3);

    System.out.println(lookup.get("Two"));
    System.out.println(lookup.get("three"));
}
```

Outputs:

```
2
3
```

Comment: hashMap performance is O(1)  &  TreeMap performance O(log(n)) 

read this Question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap` uses the key's `equals(Object)` method  (in combination with `hashCode()`), and `String.equals()` is case-sensitive. So if you want a case-insensitive key, you have to define your own key class with a proper `equals()` and `hashCode()`. In total, is possibly easier to use `toLowerCase()` on all key strings.

Comment: Can you please provide some support for your answer? Eg. a link etc. Thanks