# groupingBy returns Object for key as Map when it should use String

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Let's say I have a list of Brand objects. The POJO contains a getName() that returns a string. I want to build a 
`Map<String, Brand>`
out of this with the String being the name... but I want the key to be **case insensitive**.

How do I make this work using Java streams? Trying:

```
brands.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(brand -> brand.getName().toLowerCase()));
```

doesn't work, which I think is because I'm not using groupBy correctly.

Comment: No- right off the bat I realize I shouldn't be using groupingBy because that returns a List. Let me clarify the return type a little more... there! so the problem is it doesn't compile because it tries to return an Object key

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) the results into a [case insensitive map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212562/is-there-a-good-way-to-have-a-mapstring-get-and-put-ignoring-case)

```
Map<String, Brand> map = brands
     .stream()
     .collect(
          Collectors.toMap(
              Brand::getName, // the key
              Function.identity(), // the value
              (first, second) -> first, // how to handle duplicates
              () -> new TreeMap<String, Brand>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))); // supply the map implementation
```

`Collectors#groupBy` won't work here because it returns a `Map<KeyType, List<ValueType>>`, but you don't want a `List` as a value, you just want a `Brand`, from what I've understood.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios. I feel like I shouldn't use this implementation yet because no one on my team would understand it. Hah! I'm sure that will change with time but the solution definitely works.

Comment: BTW: can you explain why groupingBy doesn't work for my situation?

Comment: @IcedDante From your question, you seem to want a `Map<String, Brand>`. `groupBy` would have returned a `Map<String, List<Brand>>`. That's what it does, it groups (`List`) values by some property.